# Form helper using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, nested, formhelper

I have to manage a form that has a table with the attribute "user_id".
I'd like to have the user write the name of someone he wants to invite directly instead of using the id.

This is my table

```
create_table "participations", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "event_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
```

In my participation model:

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base


attr_accessible :event_id, :user_id,  
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :user


end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :id, :name,  
has_many :participations


end
```

Comment: Please send some more details what you exactly wants to do

Comment: I'd like to have a form in which i add participants to an event with a given event.id I am able to do so only if i insert in my form the user_id but i want to be able to invite users through their names.

Comment: Your users are dynamic or they already saved in your applications. If you want only names than only add a name field which will save their name .

Comment: They are already saved in my application

Comment: See my answer, i have used auto complete in my app

Answer (score 0):

In your form just add this code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#user_auto_complete').typeahead({
      name: 'user',
      local: <%= @users.blank? ? [].to_json : raw (@users.map {|user| user.name }.to_json(:only => [:name ])) %>
    });

  });
</script>

<form>

<input type="text" id="user_auto_complete" name="user_id" value='<%= (!@participant.user_id.blank?)? "#{@users.find(@participant.user_id).name}" : ""%>'>

</form>
```

Hope this will help you